# What's wrong with my code? (obj c tweak development)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tweak

So, I'm new to tweak development and obj c and I'm trying to change the style of dock with this code

```
%hook SBWallpaperEffect
-(void)setStyle: (NSInteger)arg1{
    arg1 = 5;
}
%end
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you add more clue to solve the problem? Your function `-(void)setStyle: (NSInteger)arg1{
    arg1 = 5;
}` is true.

Comment: @CuongNguyen This is all the code i have and the number 5 i set to arg1 is supposed to change the dock style to a softer blur or if i change it to 14 it maked it dark like noctis did. But my code doesnt work. It works on flex tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured out that im using NSInteger instead of long long. Like this:

> - (void)setStyle:(long long)arg1;

Also, i was using

> SBWallpaperEffect

Instead of

> SBWallpaperEffectView

And i should've set the value inside **%orig**

So, this is the right way to write it:

```
%hook SBWallpaperEffectView
- (void)setStyle:(long long)arg1{
    arg1 = 5;
    %orig(arg1);
    return;
}
%end
```

Comment: The `return;` at the end is redundant.

Comment: @FireMango oh yeah i forgot to remove it when i was testing it thx

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think this is the typical kind of pointer problem many programmers face. You are passing a `NSInteger` to the function, and `arg1` is a `copy` of the value that is passed in. In other words, no matter how you change `arg1` inside the function, the original variable does not change.

To make things more clear, look at the following code snippet:

```
NSInteger myInteger = 0;
NSInteger arg1;
arg1 = myInteger;
arg1 = 5;
// myInteger is still 0!
```

Changing `arg1` does not change the value of `myInteger`, and that's what you're doing in your function. The `arg1` copies the value of the integer passed in, be set to 5, and then gets released at the end of the function.

Instead, try this:

```
-(void)setStyle:(NSInteger *)arg1{
    arg1 = 5;
}
```

and then call the function like this:

```
NSInteger myInteger = 0;
[self setStyle:&myInteger];
//myInteger is now 5!
```

Now you will get the result you want.

If you don't want to deal with these messy pointer stuff, use the returning value of the function to pass the number like this:

```
-(NSInteger)getStyle:(NSInteger)arg1{
    // do some calculation
    arg1 += 5;
    return arg1;
}
```

or something like this (with no parameters):

```
-(NSInteger)getStyle{
    return 5;
}
```

and call it like:

```
myInteger = [self getStyle:myInteger];
//  or
myInteger = [self getStyle];
```

Now `myInteger` will also be 5. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I get the error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'

Comment: I still get the use of undeclared identifier 'self' error

Comment: So i looked in the sdk and this is what i found: - (void)setStyle:(long long)arg1; any way to set the value for arg1?

Comment: The code I gave you should work. Use `self` for `UIViews` and `self.view` for other views. hope this fixes your problem.